# Redirect After Post in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the [Redirect After Post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern in my ASP.NET MVC application. I have
the following scenario:

1. User goes to `/controller/index` where he is asked to fill a form.
2. Form values are POSTed to `/controller/calculate`.
3. The `Calculate` action performs calculation based on input and instantiates a complex object containing the results of the operation. This object is stored in `TempData` and user is redirected to `/controller/result`.
4. `/controller/result` retrieves the result from `TempData` and renders them to the user.

The problem with this approach is that if the user hits F5 while viewing the results in `/controller/result` the page can no longer be rendered as `TempData` has been expired and the result object is no longer available.

This behavior is not desired by the users. One possible solution would be instead of redirecting after the POST, just rendering the results view. Now if the user hits F5 he gets a browser dialog asking if he wants to repost the form. This also was not desired.

One possible solution I thought of was to serialize the result object and passing it in the URL before redirecting but AFAIK there are some limitations in the length of a GET request and if the object gets pretty big I might hit this limitation (especially if base64 encoded).

Another possibility would be to use the `Session` object instead of `TempData` to persist the results. But before implementing this solution I would like to know if there's a better way of doing it.

---

UPDATE:

Further investigating the issue I found out that if I re-put the result object in `TempData` inside the `/controller/result` action it actually works:

```
public ActionResult Result()
{
    var result = TempData["result"];
    TempData["result"] = result;
    return View(result);
}
```

But this feels kind of dirty. Could there be any side effects with this approach (such as switching to out-of-process session providers as currently I use InProc)?

Comment: When you say "redirect" are you calling RedirectToAction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store it in the Session with some unique key and pass the key as part of the url.  Then as long as the session is alive they can use the back/forward button to their heart's content and still have the URL respond properly.  Alternatively, you could use the ASP cache, but I'd normally reserve that for objects that are shared among users.  Of course, if you used the parameters to the calculation as the key and you found the result in the cache, you could simply re-use it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. I would try to implement it with an unique key passed in the url.

Answer (score 2):

I think redirect after post makes much more sense when the resulting Url is meaningfull.
In your case it would mean that all data required for the calculation is in the Url of /controller/result.

/controller/calculate would not do the calculation but /controller/result.

If you can get this done thinks get pretty easy: You hash the values required for the calculation and use it as the key for the cache. If the user refreshes he only hits the cache.

If you cant have a meaningfull url you could post to /controller/index. If the user hits F5 calculation would start again, but a cache with the hash as key would help again.

Comment: I need to validate input before calculating and if there's an error show the same form with pre-filled values and error fields marked in red. If calculation was done in the Result action how would I handle ModelState errors? Should I redirect back to the Index action and put again all the input values and validation errors to the TempData so that I can correctly show the form?

Comment: Its harder to have validation in result. I would redirect to it with validated values. The easiest way is to post to index and validate data / display errors there.

Answer (score 1):

TempData is generally considered useful for passing messages back to the user not for storing working entities (a user refresh will nuke the contents of TempData).

I don't know of more appropriate place than the session to store this kind of information. I think the general idea is keep session as small as possible though. Personally I usually write some wrappers to add and remove specific objects to session. Cleaning them up manually where possible.

Alternatively you can store in a database in which you purge stale items on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

I might adopt a similar idea to a lot of banks on their online banking sites by using one-time keys to verify all POSTs. You can integrate it into a html helper for forms and into your service layer (for example) for verification.

Let's say that you only want to post any instance of a form once. Add a guid to the form. If the form does not post back and the data is committed then you want to invalidate the guid and redirect to the GET action. If say the form was not valid, when the page posts back you need a new (valid) guid there in the form waiting for the next post attempt.

GUIDs are generated as required and added to a table in your DB. As they are invalidated (by POSTS, whether successful or not) they are flagged in the table. You may want to trim the table at 100 rows.. or 1000, depending on how heavy your app will be and how many rendered but not yet posted forms you may have at any one time.

I haven't really fine tuned this design but i think it might work. It wont be as smelly as the TempData and you can still adhere to the PRG pattern.

Remember, with PRG you dont want to send the new data to the GET action in a temp variable of some sort. You want to query it back from the data store, where it's now committed to.

Comment: Currently the application has no datastore. It performs all the work in-memory (only calculations and no persistence). That's why I considered using TempData or Session as a temporary datastore.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael stated, TempData has a single purpose -> store an object for one trip only and only one trip.  As I understand it, TempData is essentially using the same Session object as you might use but it will automatically remove the object from the session on the next trip.

Stick with Session imho rather than push back in to TempData.